# Multi-objective optimization using mco package

Tags: r

I am using `mco` package provided by it. I have two objectives:

```
f1=x1(16+y^2)^1/2+x2(1+y^2)^1/2
f2=max(AC,BC)
```

How do I code this using `nsga2`? Could anyone provide examples?

Comment: I think you have it backwards. You provide the examples.

Comment: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4a93/e921a6674569a9f6a38f4375987c5db4e62a.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The documentation provides examples on how to add a new function to evaluate using the package. The document is given [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mco/mco.pdf). Taking an example from the document, for `VNT` problem

```
## VNT problem:
vnt <- function(x) {
y <- numeric(3)
xn <- crossprod(x, x)
y[1] <- xn/2 + sin(xn);
y[2] <- (crossprod(c(3, -2), x) + 4)^2/8 + (crossprod(c(1, -1), x) + 1)^2/27 + 15
y[3] <- 1/(xn + 1) - 1.1*exp(-xn)
return (y)
}

r2 <- nsga2(vnt, 2, 3,
generations=150, popsize=100,
lower.bounds=rep(-3, 2),
upper.bounds=rep(3, 2))

plot(r2)
```